# Issue with useState and React.FC in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm fairly new to typescript having been a dirty JS developer for awhile now, but I'm getting an error that doesn't make any sense. Essentially the compiler appears to be telling me that I'm using useState outside of a functional component or custom hook, yet the TS definition for my component is React.FC. Any help understanding what is actually going on would be nice.

The entirety of nameRandomizer.tsx is here:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const nameRandomizer: React.FC = () => {
  const [inputWords, setInputWords] = useState<string>('Test Text');

  return (
    <div className="NavFlexItemStatic">{inputWords}</div>
  );
};

export default nameRandomizer;
```

Yields the following errors while trying to build the react project:

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/navigation/nameRandomizer.tsx
Line 3:39:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "nameRandomizer: React.FC" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-site@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-site@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/william/.npm/_logs/2020-12-05T19_18_29_436Z-debug.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [need to name custom components with an upper case](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#components).

> Component names **should also always start with a capital letter** (`<Wrapper/>` not `<wrapper/>`).

```
const NameRandomizer: React.FC = () => {
  ...
};

<NameRandomizer/>
```

For now, the linter thinks you calling a hook from a simple function (as the error states) which fails the build process.